# Push Data from Web Application to Desktop Application using through SendKey

Tags: c#, web, automation, desktop-application, sendkeys

```
Process p = Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Desktop\desktop_d\desk.exe");
p.WaitForInputIdle();
IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
```

The application exe file executed, then I wanted to the data set each textbox and Submit button click event, I want to execute from the web application .

Any suggestion, please share the comments. It's helpful for me.

Comment: Seems like you are looking for automation scripts.

Comment: yes exactly. @D.J.